# Host to Host SSH Tunnel

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vpn, tunnel

I want to create a full SSH tunnel between two Ubuntu 12.04 servers, (I found out about SSHuttle but because of a bug in the handling of file descriptors it will crash under high load) very much like IPSEC but because I need it only for two hosts the complexity of creating a full fledged IPSEC configuration looks to be an overkill.

What I want to achieve is that all the data going between server1 and server2 will be encrypted without needing to create thousand of SSH dynamic ports.

Comment: Man thank you , for your question I have found a very good blog for sys admins. I will post the answer too.

Comment: What do you mean by "full ssh tunnel" ?

Comment: Full SSH tunnel as in passing all the ports\connections\data\sessions and not only a single port forward like with SSH's -D options for dynamic ports

Comment: Then, I would recommend using VPN software (such as openvpn) instead of ssh. setting up openVPN between two host is really simple.

Answer (score 2):

This answer belongs to [brandonchecketts](http://www.brandonchecketts.com/archives/creating-a-permanent-ssh-tunnel-between-linux-servers).

Assume You have two hosts named as Host-A and Host-B. Now we are going to create a SSH Tunnel between these two and make sure that Tunnel is up & live for all the time.

Configuration Need to be done for Host-A:

Open your terminal , turn into root and paste the code one after one

```
useradd -d /home/tunnel tunnel
passwd tunnel 
su - tunnel
```

next step is about creating a SSH key

In the terminal paste as

```
ssh-keygen
```

and then choose default choice for all prompt and copy the key with

```
cat /.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Now this time we have to configuration for Host-B

Open your terminal and execute these commands

```
useradd -d /home/tunnel tunnel
passwd tunnel 
su - tunnel
```

and in terminal type as

```
mkdir .ssh
vi .ssh/authorized_keys
```

It will open a file in terminal and paste the above copied key from Host-A.

Now in the terminal type as

vi /home/tunnel/check_ssh_tunnel.sh

and paste as

```
createTunnel() {
    /usr/bin/ssh -f -N -L13306:hostb:3306 -L19922:hostb:22 tunnel@hostb
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo Tunnel to hostb created successfully
    else
        echo An error occurred creating a tunnel to hostb RC was $?
    fi
}
## Run the 'ls' command remotely.  If it returns non-zero, then create a new connection
/usr/bin/ssh -p 19922 tunnel@localhost ls
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo Creating new tunnel connection
    createTunnel
fi
```

save and close and make it executable with

```
chmod 700 /home/tunnel/check_ssh_tunnel.sh
```

and then run the script, it will start a Tunnel with remote PC.

Read that above link, it is must.

Comment: But this forward only one port, no ?

Comment: you want multiple ports right ?

Comment: @Rémi check this out http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19242/ssh-tunnelling-with-multiple-dynamic-port-forwardings

Comment: This will only create a one port tunnel, it is cool and very elegant but not what I needed.

Comment: @Ba7a7chy its k , glad its helped you a bit